# Invalid UTF-8 sequence handling in PHP

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have a bunch of user-supplied data that I do minimal processing with, such as escaping  characters with `htmlentities()`.  Unfortunately that data may be one of a few different encodings (yes, that's something that should have been canonicalized to UTF-8 before, but now there are lots of terabytes of data and it's hard to re-mediate).

Recently I was rather surprised when certain documents refused to display even though the data was definitely there with no log errors or exceptions.  After some debugging it looks like (from `phpsh`):

```
php> var_dump(htmlentities("Hello\xbdWorld", ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'));
string(0) ""

php> var_dump(error_get_last());
NULL
```

I am aware that the problem here is that the data is actually ISO-8859-1 encoded, and that I told `htmlentities()` to treat it as UTF-8 (I'm working on converting everything to UTF-8 but that will take very long).  My problem is just that the error handling is so bizarre (non-existent).  Tracking down these issues becomes nightmarish.  Is there a way that's built into PHP (e.g., a configuration variable or something) to make it so that this does something less surprising than return an empty string in an error state?

If not, I'm thinking of redefining the offending function(s) using `override_function()` or something to call the function and ensure the return value makes sense, and if not, throw an exception.  I found a list of dangerous functions on [this very helpful page](http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/utf-8)

Comment: Check out: http://www.sitepoint.com/bringing-unicode-to-php-with-portable-utf8/ and http://pageconfig.com/post/portable-utf8

Comment: @mkaatman [Portable UTF-8](http://pageconfig.com/post/portable-utf8) is a good library but it is not for this specific purpose. The problem will still remain. A feasible solution may be on the fly conversion to utf-8 using utf8_encode() php function. Or you may also use 'ISO-8859-1' in your function instead of 'UTF-8' as the third argument, if it fulfills you purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Converting your ISO-8859-1 data to UTF8 is actually not something that will take a long time. You can automate the process in php by looping the `utf8_encode()` function. That function may also be very useful to you for addressing your current issue with displaying ISO data in a UTF8 document.

Comment: Those documents are in a production database that uses ISO-8859-1 encoding.  Taking the servers down for as long as it would take to do this isn't acceptable.  I am aware that the conversion is cheap computationally because for probably 99% of the bytes it's just a NOP.

Comment: gotcha. you can still fetch the data in its original ISO-8859-1 format and run it through the `UTF8_encode()` function to display it without changing your HTML charset.